# Spring-integration convert xml configuration into java config

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I want to convert my xml config into Java class config but i can't find a solution. For example a piece of my config:

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn" directory="file:${java.io.tmpdir}/spring-integration-samples/input"
                              filename-regex="^.*\.(xml|json)$" >
    <int:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="5000"/>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>


<int:service-activator input-channel="filesIn"
                       output-channel="filesOut"
                       ref="handler"/>

<file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesOut" directory="file:${java.io.tmpdir}/spring-integration-samples/output"
                               delete-source-files="true"/>



<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesContent" directory="file:${java.io.tmpdir}/spring-integration-samples/output"
                              filename-regex="^.*\.(xml|json)$" prevent-duplicates="true">
    <int:poller id="poller2" fixed-delay="5000"/>
 </file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

How can i made the same thing but with use sftp (src directory) on my local machine and also how to write this config in java class. Give me any suggestion i looking for answer but i can't find the way out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should start from the [Spring Integration Java DSL Reference Manual](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference). There you will find general concepts of the Java DSL and how that is related to the XML config.

The SFTP Inbound/Outbound Channel Adapter configuration samples you can find in the appropriate Reference Manual [Chapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#_configuring_with_the_java_dsl_12). For example that `<int:service-activator>` in Java DSL may look like:

```
.handle(handler)
```

Where you don't have channel definitions if you declare everything in a single `IntegrationFLow`.

Comment: Ok but i want to make that using Annotations. Can u give me any advice how to to the same thing using annotations? because i can;t find the way to replace my outbound channel adapter. @ArtemBilan

Comment: The Outbound Channel Adapter is a `@ServiceActivator`. See the same SFTP chapter: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#_configuring_with_java_configuration_19